# Saving results of query from Big Query python api to CSV

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have to fetch the data from Big query python API and trying to save the query results locally as a CSV file. Here's the code for loading:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=r"C:\Users\Rishi\Downloads\localis-backend-8d07970f5e24.json"

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
    SELECT name, SUM(number) as total_people
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
    WHERE state = 'TX'
    GROUP BY name, state
    ORDER BY total_people DESC
    LIMIT 20
"""
query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request
```

Now for saving to a CSV, I tried to iterate into each row and save it into the list and finally converting to dataframe.

```
ls=[]

for row in query_job:
    ls.append(row)    
    
    
ls_df = pd.DataFrame(ls)
```

Eventhough, its giving me the results, but it's not retaining the same schema as we see in the Big Query. What I'm missing here? Is there a better way to convert Big Query results to dataframe and then to a CSV?

Comment: You have a typo - `pandas.DataFrame` not `pandas.Dataframe`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Hey Jack Smith, Thanks.  sorry my bad. It worked but still its not retaining the schema of the original table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this with a function.

```
query_df = query.to_dataframe()
```

Then we can save this file to a csv.

```
query_df.to_csv("Your_filename.csv")
```